# alphabetically order role drop-down selection in dashboard

Tags: users, dashboard, user-roles, order

The site I'm working on will have a very large number of unique user roles via a members plugin. Because of that, I'd like to have the Role drop-down selection on the Add New User page to display roles alphabetically, rather than descending order of creation.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost the same approach *One Trick Pony* has chosen, but I am using translated names and `uasort()` (to preserve the keys):

```
add_filter( 'editable_roles', 't5_sort_editable_roles' );

/**
 * Array of roles.
 *
 * @wp-hook editable_roles
 * @param   array $roles
 * @return  array
 */
function t5_sort_editable_roles( $roles )
{
    uasort( $roles, 't5_uasort_editable_roles' );
    return $roles;
}
/**
 * Compare translated role names.
 *
 * @param  array $a First role
 * @param  array $b Second role
 * @return number
 */
function t5_uasort_editable_roles( $a, $b )
{
    return strcasecmp(
        translate_user_role( $a['name'] ),
        translate_user_role( $b['name'] )
    );
}
```

[As a plugin on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/4196278).

Comment: @Chirico See my update, the first version was buggy.

Comment: Thanks again, I just started running into problems with the first version. looks like things are as they should be now.

Comment: Hi, Is there a way the current sorting order can be reversed? If yes, that would be helpful if you could please the same in your code or leave a comment as to how to do that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there's a filter that you can use in the `get_editable_roles` function (which is called in that page):

```
add_filter('editable_roles', function($roles){

  // sort alphabetically (ignores case)
  usort($roles, function($a, $b){
    return strcasecmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
  });   

  return $roles;
});
```